# Are there any metrics on a user's behavior in up/down-voting other questions after being up/down-voted on their own question?

Tags: discussion

I can imagine there is a wealth of information in human behavior in this site just by looking at how users respond positively or negatively on this site.

I was thinking about it myself when I realized I was more likely to upvote someone else's question or answer after being upvoted myself, and also stick around the site more. But when I'm downvoted, I feel like I'm more likely to just take a break from the site and come back when my pride has recovered a bit. But if I do stick around, I'm more likely to downvote other questions, although I like to think that I'm only choosing ones that are deserving of downvotes instead of just being vindictive about it.

I could picture a very simple model for looking at user behavior:

> Inputs:
>
> - A user is upvoted or downvoted
>
> Outputs:
>
> - A user upvotes or downvotes other questions
> - A user's votes are more or less critical than other votes on that item
> - A user increases or decreases their typical activity on the site for that period of time

Comment: You can't grab the voting behaviour of users though @nhgrif

Comment: @Bart Ah, I see `UserId` column isn't filled in for the Votes table...

Comment: It's all removed before  being put online @nhgrif

Comment: Voting is about posts not about people so no feelings should be involved.

Comment: I am not sure how much it would tell you about behavior in general since votes are supposed to be merit based, but a fair number can be tactical votes.  Both of which would skew what you are looking for,

Comment: And probably a fair number are groveling to superiors...

Comment: The fact that so many people think that downvotes "should not involve feelings"explains a lot. Whether a downvote is intended as a statement of disagreement or a merit based assessment, it still amounts to a blanket rejection of one's thoughts and/or work product. Given the lack of any associated explanation inherent in the SO design, it's only natural that for many/most people downvotes result in "emotional pain" or "hurt feelings" that drive them away to some extent. Fortunately, you can't downvote comments so at least this medium remains as a relatively safe alternative.

Comment: @rene: I assume this is in the same way that cancer researchers "should" be paid more than sports stars, or that we "should" all know better than to feed trolls.